# Log an arbitrary XML structure using logstash-logback-encoder

Tags: java, json, xml, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using the [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder) library for logging traffic of a Java messaging service. The logs are stored in JSON files which are sent to Elasticsearch. So far I have been adding extra fields such as `client_id` or `execution_time` to the log entries using  `net.logstash.logback.marker.Markers.appendEntries()`. There is, however, a new requirement that the entire XML payload of each message must also be logged.

Suppose a message payload looks like this:

```xml
<Message>
  <Header source="foo" destination="bar">
    <!-- ... -->
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Body>
</Message>
```

Then the corresponding log entry should take the following form:

```json
{
  "@timestamp": "2022-05-19T18:07:42.125+01:00",
  "@version": "1",
  "message": "...",
  "level": "DEBUG",
  "client_id": "35a81e10-8584-4a9d-bf8c-912a09f4cd0e",
  "client_address": "126.111.228.191",
  "topic": "foo/bar",
  "execution_time": 44,
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "payload": {
    "Message": {
      "Header": {
        "@source": "foo",
        "@destination": "bar",
        "...": "...",
        "Body": {
          "...": "..."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "...": "..."
}
```

How would i achieve this output in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Have you taken a look at [logstash's xml filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-xml.html)

You can find some exemple on how to use it [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/xml-filter-example/264698)